# Select Rows With the Greatest Value In One Column When Another Column Has matching Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL table which contains a list of financial transactions with their corresponding accounts, dates, and closing account balance (balance after transaction is processed).

| Date | TransactionId | ClosingBalance | AccountId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-06-11 | 51330001 | -48.39 | 1033938 |
| 2015-06-11 | 51330002 | -54.92 | 1033938 |
| 2015-06-11 | 51330003 | -85.15 | 1033938 |
| 2015-06-12 | 51330004 | 114.85 | 1033938 |
| 2015-06-12 | 51330005 | 113.18 | 1033938 |
| 2015-06-12 | 51330006 | 110.55 | 1033938 |
| 2015-06-12 | 51330007 | 107.86 | 1033938 |
| 2015-06-12 | 51330008 | 98.84 | 1033938 |
| 2015-06-12 | 51330009 | 56.51 | 1033938 |
| 2015-06-15 | 51330010 | 1284.08 | 1033941 |
| 2015-06-15 | 51330012 | 1334.08 | 1033938 |
| 2015-06-15 | 51330013 | 1332.41 | 1033938 |
| 2015-06-15 | 51330015 | 1329.78 | 1033938 |

An account may have multiple transactions on any given day. I'm trying to write a query which will return the last transaction (with the highest transaction number) for each account on each day essentially giving me the ending daily balance for that account.

| Date | TransactionId | ClosingBalance | AccountId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-06-11 | 51330003 | -85.15 | 1033938 |
| 2015-06-12 | 51330009 | 56.51 | 1033938 |
| 2015-06-15 | 51330010 | 1284.08 | 1033941 |
| 2015-06-15 | 51330015 | 1329.78 | 1033938 |

Comment: please share the insert script for this data. It is very difficult to write data scripts for writing query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two quick options.  Both use with window function `row_number() over()` and both will create the same results (except for the extra column RN)

**First is WITH TIES**

```
Select top 1 with ties * 
 From  YourTable
 Order By row_number() over (partition by AccountID,Date order by [TransactionId] desc)
```

**Second with with a CTE**

```
with cte as (
Select *
      ,RN = row_number() over (partition by AccountID,Date order by [TransactionId] desc)
 From  YourTable
)
Select * from cte where RN=1
```

`WITH TIES` looks cleaner and easier but the second option is a nudge more performant